# IE 8 and getElementById() that is dynamic throws error

Tags: javascript, dynamic, internet-explorer-8

I have a function that is called whenever a select changes. If the select had an ID of "foo" there'd be a text field with an ID of "foo_other" after it that by default is styled "display:none".

If a value of "Other" is picked from the select, the function is supposed to display the text field, and set focus to it. If anything other than "Other" is chosen, it should hide the field and remove anything entered.

Works in FF, IE throws an error "Object required". I was trying to avoid doing an eval() around the dynamic variable... Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
function checkOther(inObj){
    var other_form_id = inObj.name + "_other"; 
    if(inObj.value == 'Other')
    {
        document.getElementById(other_form_id).style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById(other_form_id).focus();
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(other_form_id).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(other_form_id).value = '';   
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are acceptable answers to some of your questions, I would recommend you mark some as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you are having multiple IDs in one document (which is invalid), and IE is more picky about it than FF is. Could that be?

Comment: I checked and I have unique ID's... Thanks though, and I'll try to be more conscious of the "accepted" part.

Comment: @Don strange. Can you `alert()` an actual ID, and edit that in together with the corresponding HTML?

Comment: thanks for the help. It turns out it was not IE, it was "ME"... I had renameded the first id, so when it tried to append "_other" onto the end of it, it was a different name. Just forgot to rename the text item to match. Thanks for confirming it SHOULD work so I knew to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The stupid idiots from microsoft are getting the first **id OR NAME**.
I have a dynamically generated javascript and name and id of one html element (input) are different. But instead getting the element with specified ID, the idiots of IE8 are getting the first element with that NAME.

I believed they are idiots even i was working 15+ years as windows (visual studio) developer, but i didn't expect such a stupidness ...

Even later,
Hope this will help someone else, not the author of the post.

My solution was to add "id_" prefix for the id tag in order to be sure that the idiots are going to get exactly the normal one, nad not another with with the same name. In my case i'm using id tag for javascript things and the name tag for saving to the DB when the form is sent.